# How to extract specific column from text file in C?

Tags: c, text, multiple-columns

I have a text file of 4 rows 3 columns ex:

```
1 2 5
3 5 6
8 8 2
1 1 0
```

I want to move from one file to the other file the third column so the new text will look like this

```
5
6
2
0
```

I've done this with fscanf so that every third time I use fscanf to insert it to the new file
Is there a better way to access the third column other that scanning the first 2 numbers?
Thanks

Comment: No. Not really. If you are 100% sure that the 3rd column is always exactly 1 character and at character position 4 (0-based), you can read the whole line and index it.

Comment: When you use `fscanf` to convert integer values you cannot be sure that the input lines contain 3 columns as expected. Better read the whole line with `fgets`, scan it with `sscanf` and check if the return value (= number of successfully converted values) is 3. You can even use a format that would convert 4 values to detect possible lines with more than 3 columns.

Comment: If your input file has 6 values on one line, it will be difficult with `scanf` to distinguish that from 6 values spread across two lines.  Similarly if you have 6 values spread across 6 lines.  `scanf` is probably the wrong tool if you care about whitespace in the input.

Answer (score 0):

`*scanf` is far more complex than you need for something this simple.  When you can avoid `scanf`, you should.  (You can almost always avoid it, where "almost" is just me hedging).  This is a simple task, which should be done with simple tools.  For example:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* A simple implementation of `awk '{print $3}'` */

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int c;
    int column = 0;
    int last = ' ';
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF ){
        if( ! isspace(c) && isspace(last)){
            column += 1;
        }
        if( c == '\n' ){
            column = 0;
            putchar(c);
        } else if( column == 3 ){
            putchar(c);
        }
        last = c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see. This worked for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char line[25];
    FILE * file;

    file = fopen("text1.txt", "r");

    fscanf(file, "%[^\n]", &line);

    printf("%s", line + strlen(line) - 1);

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, you will store an entire line in an array of chars, then you will print certain pieces of that string (array of chars). With that in mind, you can make a way to do with multiple lines.

Hope this helped you out.

Comment: `FILE * file; ... printf("%s", file + strlen(file) - 1);` WUT!?!?!? `strlen(file)` is supposed to do just what, exactly?

Comment: Print the last column, I tested it. He wanted to read from file and get the last column printed out, right?

Comment: Read your code again - carefully.

Comment: Fixed it, how about this? Sorry lol. This, however, should work.

Comment: egarding" `fscanf(file, "%[^\n]s", &line);`  This is saying that the newline must be followed by the character `s`  This is an error as the next character in `stdin` will be '\n', not `s`.   Suggest: `fscanf(file, "%[^\n]", &line);`

Comment: for robust code, always check the returned value from fopen(), and `fscanf()`

Comment: Thanks @user3629249, I'll fix it.